# Including a GPL-licensed library through a CDN

Tags: javascript, licensing, gpl, mit-license

I'm planning to use [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co) in my MIT-licensed open-source JavaScript project. The [license for open-source usage](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/license.html) is GPL. Can I link the file via a CDN into my project, or is this considered a "derivative work?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling into the Flickity library from your project, you are creating a derived work as far as the GPL is concerned.

However, this does not mean that your code must be under the GPL license as well. Your code must be under a license that is compatible with the GPL ([which the MIT license is](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#Expat)) and people who make changes to your code have to comply to the rules of the GPL license.
This means effectively that it is not allowed to make a closed-source (derived) version of your project without removing the dependency on Flickity.

Comment: The author told me basically the same thing: https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/423#issuecomment-235395360

Comment: Please point out the source for "MIT-License is compatible to GPLv3"?

Comment: @SimonSobisch: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#Expat

Answer (score -1):

The only way to include the file and use the "open-source licensing" would be to change your license to GPLv3 (otherwise you need the commercial license).

Side note: changing your license to GPLv3 *does not* mean everyone that uses your product has to provide the sources for it (this would only be covered by the AGPL).

Therefore the main impact I see is: if someone changes your code and wants to distribute it he has to use the GPLv3 himself for the distributed source.

Comment: I don't want to use GPL. I guess I'll be using a different library, then.

Comment: To clarify, this is JavaScript, it's web. The file wouldn't be included with any distributions of my project

Comment: The author seems to say otherwise: https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/423#issuecomment-235395360